# How can I turn comma separated fields into different rows?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like that:

```
A 10,30,50,70 20,40,60,80 +
```

how can I make this become:

```
A 10 20 +
A 30 40 + 
A 50 60 + 
A 70 80 +
```

I tried using this awk command, but it did not work.

```
awk '{ split($2,a,","); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]; }'
```

Comment: Does your file really only have 1 line in it? If so state that, if not show more in your sample input/output. Does the order of the output lines have to match the order of the input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another split-ed array `b`, where you kept the 3rd column elements:

```
echo "A 10,30,50,70 20,40,60,80 +" | awk '{ split($2,a,","); split($3,b,","); for (i in a) print $1, a[i],  b[i], $4; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{  split ($2, a,","); split ($3,b,",");  for (i in a) print $1, a[i], b[i], $NF; }'
```

should give you the result.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '{for (i=2;i<6;i++) print $1, $i, $(i+4), $NF}' file
A 10 20 +
A 30 40 +
A 50 60 +
A 70 80 +
```

or if you don't want to hard-code the number of fields:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '{n=NF/2; for (i=2;i<=n;i++) print $1, $i, $(i+n-1), $NF}' file
A 10 20 +
A 30 40 +
A 50 60 +
A 70 80 +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
A 10,30,50,70,90 20,40,60,80,00 +
B ab,56,is,jw,23 09,we,io,21,aw +
```

Generic solution, independent of number of comma separated values in 2nd and 3rd columns...

```
$ perl -lane '@a = split/,/,$F[1]; @b = split/,/,$F[2]; foreach (0..$#a){ print "$F[0] $a[$_] $b[$_] $F[3]" }' ip.txt 
A 10 20 +
A 30 40 +
A 50 60 +
A 70 80 +
A 90 00 +
B ab 09 +
B 56 we +
B is io +
B jw 21 +
B 23 aw +
```

And a solution similar to [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822911/4082052)

```
$ perl -F'/\s|,/' -lane 'foreach (1..5){ print "$F[0] $F[$_] $F[$_+5] $F[-1]" }' ip.txt 
A 10 20 +
A 30 40 +
A 50 60 +
A 70 80 +
A 90 00 +
B ab 09 +
B 56 we +
B is io +
B jw 21 +
B 23 aw +
```

where `foreach (1..5)` and `$F[$_+5]` indicates 5 comma separated values in 2nd and 3rd columns